# Python code giving an error - TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatti

Tags: python

I was practicing this program which asks the user to give their inputs and displays output.
I'm running the program with IDLE.

```
print "How old are you"
age= raw_input()
print "How tall are you"
height=raw_input()
print "How much do you weigh?"
weight=raw_input()

print "I am %r yrs old", "I am %r tall" , "I weigh %r” “ %(age,height,weight)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
How old are you
34
How tall are you
34
How much do you weigh?
34
I am %r yrs old I am %r tall

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/r/Documents/new.py", line 8, in <module>
    print "I am %r yrs old", "I am %r tall" , "I weigh %r" %(age,height,weight)

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: You have three separate strings, apply formatting to *each separately*.

Comment: Or better yet, make it **one longer** string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use string formatting for three separate strings. A cleaner way to do this is probably to use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and you can combine the three strings (one example given to print on new lines). Also, there is no need to have `print` and `raw_input` on separate lines.

```
age = raw_input("How old are you\n")
height = raw_input("How tall are you\n")
weight = raw_input("How much do you weigh?\n")

print "I am {} yrs old \nI am {} tall\nI weigh {}".format(age, height, weight)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python tries, to apply all 3 variables `(age,height,weight)` to the last string: "I weigh %r".

Use just one string:

```
print "I am %r yrs old, I am %r tall, I weigh %r" % (age,height,weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reformatting your code like this will give you the expected results.

```
print "How old are you"
age= raw_input()
print "How tall are you"
height=raw_input()
print "How much do you weigh?"
weight=raw_input()
print ("I am %r yrs old" + " I am %r tall" + " I weigh %r” ) %(age,height,weight)
```

The % operator works as a binary operator between the string and the tuple provided, and its precedence is greater than the `,` operator. This means that it will be applied on the last string only, and then the `,` operator is applied.

Your expression `"I am %r yrs old", "I am %r tall" , "I weigh %r” “ %(age,height,weight)` gets bracketed as `("I am %r yrs old"), ("I am %r tall") , ("I weigh %r” “ %(age,height,weight) )`

hence the error.

Comment: `"I am %r yrs old" + " I am %r tall" + " I weigh %r” “ %(age,height,weight)` suffers from exactly the same mistake.

Comment: @vaultah : sorry, Did not bracket the code properly. Thanks for the tip! (edited the post)